# How to find out EventProperty name?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, event-log

My C# application subscribes to Windows Event Log messages:

```
var subscriptionQuery = new EventLogQuery(Settings.Default.LogPath, PathType.LogName, Settings.Default.LogQuery);
_watcher = new EventLogWatcher(subscriptionQuery);
_watcher.EventRecordWritten += EventLogEventRead;
```

When message occurs `EventLogEventRead` handler reseives a `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord` object, containing event data. This information includes a collection of `EventProperty` objects.
The problem is: `EventProperty` only defines a value, not the name of the property. However, when I open the same event in Windows Event Log Viewer, it shows properties with names.
Now the question is: How do I get event propery names?

Answer (score 9):

I finally figured it out! 
You are intended to use [`EventLogPropertySelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogpropertyselector) to specify XPath expressions to select the properties you want. Then, instead of calling `EventRecord.Properties`, call [`EventLogRecord.GetPropertyValues(EventLogPropertySelector)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord.getpropertyvalues). The returned values are correlated by index with the XPath expressions that you specified when you created the `EventLogPropertySelector`.

For a C++ example which shows you what the XPath expressions should look like, see https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/WES/rendering-events:

> ```cpp
> ...
>
> LPWSTR ppValues[] = {L"Event/System/Provider/@Name", L"Event/System/Channel"};
> DWORD count = sizeof(ppValues)/sizeof(LPWSTR);
>
> // Identify the components of the event that you want to render. In this case,
> // render the provider's name and channel from the system section of the event.
> // To get user data from the event, you can specify an expression such as
> // L"Event/EventData/Data[@Name=\"<data name goes here>\"]".
> hContext = EvtCreateRenderContext(count, (LPCWSTR*)ppValues, EvtRenderContextValues);
>
> ...
> ```

Here’s an example in C# which demonstrates pulling only the needed values for each event type:

```cs
var query = new EventLogQuery(
    "Security",
    PathType.LogName,
    "*[System[EventID=4624 or EventID=4634]]");

using (var loginEventPropertySelector = new EventLogPropertySelector(new[]
{
    // (The XPath expression evaluates to null if no Data element exists with the specified name.)
    "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='TargetUserSid']",
    "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='TargetLogonId']",
    "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='LogonType']",
    "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='ElevatedToken']",
    "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='WorkstationName']",
    "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='ProcessName']",
    "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='IpAddress']",
    "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='IpPort']"
}))
using (var logoffEventPropertySelector = new EventLogPropertySelector(new[]
{
    "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='TargetUserSid']",
    "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='TargetLogonId']"
}))
using (var reader = new EventLogReader(query))
{
    // In C# 8: while (reader.ReadEvent() is { } ev)
    while (reader.ReadEvent() is var ev && ev != null)
    {
        using (ev)
        {
            switch (ev.Id)
            {
                case 4624:
                {
                    var loginPropertyValues = ((EventLogRecord)ev).GetPropertyValues(loginEventPropertySelector);
                    var targetUserSid = (SecurityIdentifier)loginPropertyValues[0];
                    // ...
                    break;
                }
                case 4634:
                {
                    var logoffPropertyValues = ((EventLogRecord)ev).GetPropertyValues(logoffEventPropertySelector);
                    var targetUserSid = (SecurityIdentifier)logoffPropertyValues[0];
                    // ...
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The thing that made this nearly undiscoverable (besides the lack of .NET documentation) was that `EventLogReader.ReadEvent` returns `EventRecord` which you then have to cast to `EventLogRecord`. This is what clued me in when looking at the .NET Framework source and seeing that `EventRecord.Properties` ultimately p/invokes [`EvtRender`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtrender).
https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtrender#remarks:

> There is a one-to-one relationship between the array of XPath expressions that you specified when you called the [EvtCreateRenderContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtcreaterendercontext) function and the array the values returned in the buffer.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to discover the property names if you don't already know them?

Comment: @Polynomial The only way I'm seeing to enumerate all properties without knowing names ahead of time is to call [`EventLogRecord.ToXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord.toxml). An EventLogPropertySelector entry of `"Event/EventData/Data/@Name"` only gives you the name of the first property. XPath 1 doesn't provide a string join function.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you could go about this (that I know of), but both involve parsing xml.

`EventRecord` has the function `ToXml` which includes an `UserData` section, containing all the values from that block.

The other option is a bit more complicated:
Create an `ProviderMetadata`, find the `EventMetadata` that describes the current `EventRecord`, and parse the `Template` member.
This `Template` member explains how to interpret the values (even including types), but it is in XML format.

`var meta = new ProviderMetadata(record.ProviderName).Events.Where(evt => evt.Id == eventRecord.Id).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I found in the case of event 4624 (Logon) that only 5 of the 27 properties were in the template XML, so the `ProviderMetadata` route was a dead end.